# Updating label text (dynamically) while executing another method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I am an iOS developer currently developing an iphone application. I have a simple question regarding updating the contents of a ViewController and I would greatly appreciate it if I can get someone’s feedback who is aware of this issue or have a suggested solution.

I’m writing a method that constantly updates the text of a label (and other components such as the background colour of a UIImage “box1” and “box2” ).

***The issue*** : update to the text of the label (along with other changes) only takes effect at the end when the code was done execution. So I have written a simple infinite loop that does this as follows:

```
-(void) stateTest{
    int i=0;
    for(;;){
       if (i==5) {
          self.stateLabel.text=@"Opened"; //stateLabel previously declared
          [self.box2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]]; // box2 declared as UIImage
          [self.box1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
        }
        if (i==10){
            self.stateLabel.text=@"Closed";
            [self.box2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
            [self.box1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

}
```

and in the viewDidLoad method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{       
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.stateLabel.text=@“View did Load";
    [self.box1 setBackgroundColor:[UIColorwhiteColor]];
    [self.box2 setBackgroundColor:[UIColorwhiteColor]];   
    [self stateTest];
```

}

I’m stepping through the code (breakpoints) and this is the issue I’m facing:

1. when i==5 the label text does NOT get updated (same as the color of the boxes)
2. when i==10, the label text does NOT get updated
3. The update (both the label text and the box color) show up after the code is done executing with 
   stateLabel : "Closed",
   Box 2: red background color

I have tried calling upon several functions at the end of the stateTest method (after the i++) hoping that it will “**REFRESH**” the contents of the view, label and/or the UIImage:

```
    [self.stateLabel setNeedsLayout];
    [self.stateLabel setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.box1 setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.box2 setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
```

Unfortunately non of these trials worked. I have also put an NSLog that outputs the text of the label and that works just fine, as I want. But the problem is with the dynamic update of the contents of the view controller during execution of code/method.

I would greatly appreciate any help and I am open to any suggestion

**Ideally**, this code is used in parallel with a face detection algorithm that detects the state of the mouth. There is a processImage method that processes the image every frame. I call [self stateTest] every time the image is processed; if the mouth is opened → stateLabel.text=@”Open”…etc

Thank you in advance for your contribution
Cheers!

Comment: The UI is rendered only once per run-loop iteration. Also, consider this - the refresh rate on a modern iPhone screen is like 60 frames per second. You will get through five iterations of simple loop much faster than the screen could possibly physically refresh. But regardless, the main run loop in an iOS app is largely driven by events, and you should think in terms of writing code to respond to events (including, possibly, the expiration of a countdown)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UI update will happen only when the run loop is completed. normally i run the infinite loop in background thread and post the UI update in the main thread. This will take care of the run loop.

Below code is for reference.

```
    -(void) viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.subView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 50, 30, 30)];
        self.subView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        [self.view addSubview:self.subView];



        dispatch_queue_t newQueue = dispatch_queue_create("newQueue", nil);
        dispatch_async(newQueue, ^{
            [self stateTest];
        });

    }

    -(void) stateTest{
        int i=0;
        for(;;){
            if (i==5) {
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(purpleColor) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];

            }
            if (i==10){
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(blueColor) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
              //  break;
            }
            if (i==15){
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(redColor) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
                //break;
            }
            if (i==20){
                [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(greenColor) withObject:self waitUntilDone:NO];
                break;
            }
            sleep(1);
            i++;
        }
    }

    -(void) purpleColor
    {
        [self.subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
    }

    -(void) blueColor
    {
        [self.subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }

    -(void) redColor
    {
         [self.subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    -(void) greenColor
    {
        [self.subView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it sure did make alot of difference! Just a quick question tho, would the [self performSelector..] result in the same outcome? And by that I mean does it execute the method on the main thread? If it doesnt, what is the benefits of calling a method using the performSelecor as opposed to just normally calling the method: [self method]? Thanks

Comment: Perform selector will post a message to the object similar to [self method]. There are different overloaded perform selector which helps to achieve many things apart from method call. For eg. A method can be invoked after a delay. In our case, since we are updating the UI, this needs to be posted to the main thread. So I have used the performSelectorOnMainThread to make the selector execute on main thread.

Answer (score 1):

it's not a very good idea to run a infinite loop on the main thread (uithread). Instead can I suggest you to use a timer or a dispatch event ? below is some code you can use for a timer. and I would also point you out that NSTimer cannot be re used. hence if you wish to do this operation after you invalidated it you need to re create the timer & add it into a runloop.

```
// properties in your controller
@property (nonatomic) BOOL state;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer *timer;

// where to create it . timer interval is in seconds & use decimals if you want split seconds. 
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.1 target:self selector:@selector(onTimer:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:self.timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

// timer callback method
int count = 0;
- (void)onTimer:(NSNotification *)sender
{
    self.state = !self.state;

    if (self.state)
    {
        self.box1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
        self.box2.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.box1.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
        self.box2.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }

    count++;

    if (count == 100)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"timer done" message:@"timer finished" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];
    }
}
```