# In completionblock can't change UILabel text

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Before calling performpost notifyDownloadInfo works but in completionHandler setTextForDownloadInfo calls but the label doesn't updated.

performpost is an asynchronous func that makes request with AFNetworking.

Aclass.m

```
       +(void)downloadAinformation{
          [self performPost:....... completionHandler:^() {

            [ClassUtil notifyDownloadInfo:@"string"];
            });
        }
        +(void)notifyDownloadInfo:(NSString*)str{

            NSDictionary* userInfo = @{@"text": str};
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationDownloadInfoText object:self userInfo:userInfo];

        }
```

Bclass.m

```
    - (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

        [super viewDidAppear:animated];


        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(setTextForDownloadInfo:)
                                                     name:kNotificationDownloadInfoText
                                                   object:nil];
        [self downloadData];
    }

    - (void)setTextForDownloadInfo:(NSNotification*)notification{
        NSString *str = notification.userInfo.allValues.firstObject;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
           self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str;
        });
        NSLog(@"%@",str);
    }

   -(void)downloadData{
      [Bclass downloadAinformation];
    }
```

I tried to put setTextForDownloadInfo inside it but it doesn't get inside of it:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
```

I also `performSelectorOnMainthread` and the selector method doesn't get called.

What to do to change the text in completion block after got the response from the function? Thank you.

Comment: You just need to wrap `self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str;` this in main queue. Can you post your code with dispatch main added ?

Comment: I suggest you add some more log messages.  Does the Bclass `viewDidAppear:` execute before the completion handler?

Comment: @PhillipMills sorry i am adding immediately

Comment: @PhillipMills i did edit.

Comment: @GoodSp33d i add it.

Comment: what is in the `+performPost:completionHandler:` method's body?

Comment: @holex Inside of it there is AFNetworkings post method. It returns the data through completionhandler and then call the [ClassUtil notifyDownloadInfo:@"string"];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I get help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23946588/updating-label-text-dynamically-while-executing-another-method)

Here is my code:

```
+(void)downloadAinformation{
  [self performPost:....... completionHandler:^() {

     dispatch_queue_t newQueue = dispatch_queue_create("newQueue", nil);
     dispatch_async(newQueue, ^{
                  [ClassUtil notifyDownloadInfo:@"string"];  
      });
  });
}



- (void)setTextForDownloadInfo:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSString *str = notification.userInfo.allValues.firstObject;
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateLabel:) withObject:str waitUntilDone:YES];
}

- (void)updateLabel:(NSString*)str{
    self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@e.ozmen,

```
self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str;
```

does it work?

If so, maybe downloadInfoLabel is not connected in IB?

If not, maybe there is a problem with notification posting, try to change it to

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kNotificationDownloadInfoText 
                                                    object:nil 
                                                  userInfo:userInfo];
```

Where parameter 'object' is nil.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: @e.ozmen Try with object as mentioned by Alex. Think that would solve your issue.

Comment: It works, i saw that it changes. The thing that you said didnt work :/ thanks anyway

Comment: @e.ozmen Glad that can helped you!  Can you help me now and mark your question as answered? ;)

Comment: @AlexKosyakov no sorry my wrong sentence , i mean self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str; works, not object:nil

Comment: @e.ozmen Did you check label connection in IB? It would be useful if add something like this in NSLog(@"self.downloadInfoLabel %@ str %@", self.downloadInfoLabel, str); before self.downloadInfoLabel.text = str; and post here the result.

Comment: @AlexKosyakov when i do that value seems changed but not on ui. Like something blocks ui but cant find why

Comment: @e.ozmen Did you check label connection in IB? Can you post here NSLog result?

Comment: @AlexKosyakov i checked. The values is my name.
property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *downloadInfoLabel;
2016-04-19 17:24:06.431 DemirbasSayim[3489:1502333] val: Ece

Comment: @e.ozmen man, you have a weak reference to your  downloadInfoLabel , change it to strong in property declaration: property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *downloadInfoLabel

Comment: @AlexKosyakov it didn't do anything

Comment: @e.ozmen Sorry, I forgot that it is a IBOutlet so it doesn't matter :(

Comment: @AlexKosyakov i found the answer by the way. fyi.

Comment: @e.ozmen so, what it was?

Comment: @AlexKosyakov I add the answer to the question.

Answer (score 0):

First thing I would check is to ensure if the `str` has a correct content. Use `NSLog(@"%@", str)` right after the cell is created. If the content is correct and you have doubts, that the method might be triggered in background thread, you should try using `__block NSString *string = @"Hello World!"` to ensure that the string is valid in main thread.

Second thing I would ensure if the label is sat up correctly. If you are using interface builder, double check if the connection between interface builder item and your class is provided correctly. Even more, you should check if the label has a correct frame, no other item overlays it. Maybe subview is not added to main content view for some reason.